# How to fetch product metafields in cart.js Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

How do I get product meta fields in Shopify store cart.js response?

Currently, In cart.js not providing any details of product metafields.

Answer (score 2):

You have many possible hack.
The one I would recommend if you are using CartJS is

1. In your product page, print the product metafield in the HTML

   ```
   <div class="product-page" data-metafield="{{product.metafield.namespace.value}}">
   </div>
   ```
2. When product is added, simply add the metafield as a line item property

   `var properties = {metafield : $('.product-page').data('metafield')}; 
       CartJS.addItem(variantId, 1 ,properties);`
3. The metafield is now accessible at CartJS.cart.items[i].properties[metafield] !

Answer (score 1):

** You can do this by adding the following step**

1. Add the below code in product form

```html
{% for field in product.metafields.namespace%}
             <input required class="required hidden" id="customID" type="hidden" value='{{ field | last }}' name="properties[metafields[{{ field | first }}]]"> 
    {% endfor %}
```

2. it will add in your cart object you can access it by

```html
{% for field in item.properties.metafields %}
         {{ field | first }}: {{ field | last }}
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Metafields are available client-side via Liquid. You do not need cartJS to fetch them. You can render the product metafields of interest into your own data structure of choice, and use the as you wish anyway you want.

You could also build out a StorefrontAPI based system and try GraphQL if you're really keen.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `metafield` using `item.product.metafields.your-namespace.your-key`.

Comment: This would work if you render the page using Liquid. 
But that will not help with CartJS as it s client side thus can't access metafield from Shopify's servers.

Comment: I want to access metafields of a product, can you please tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the **metafields** content of the appropriate products, collections, orders by assigning it to a variable in the liquid file.
In the `product-template.liquid`, you can use

```
   {% assign var_meta = page.metafields.meta_namespace %}
```

// You can use [the Shopify docs](https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/110057030-using-metafields-in-your-shopify-theme) to understand how you create **Metafields**

```
   {% assign key = 'meta_key' %}
   {% assign key_val_meta = meta_namespace.meta_key %}
```

Access the variable
{{key_val_meta}}

If you assign unique values to the metafield, you could use it to get the exact information you can input that information in your cart.js function.

Answer (score 0):

```
{%- if item.product.metafields.my_fields.minimum_order_quantity != blank -%}  
    {{ item.product.metafields.my_fields.minimum_order_quantity }}                                        
{%- endif -%}
```

Use this code and show data on cart page